# How to escape a space character in the field orgUnitPath in the search parameter in the users.list method of the Directory API

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to write a simple python program that uses admin-sdk (Google Directory API) to search for all users within a certain OU.  The problem I encounter is that there is a space character in one of the containers and my code breaks down at this point.  I am certain that that space is the problem. How to escape the space character or is there another solution?

Here is the code that causes the problem:

```
results = service.users().list(query='orgUnitPath=/local/example/IAM Users',customer='my_customer', maxResults=500,orderBy='email').execute()
```

If I change this to the following, then it works fine.  It only breaks at the space in the "IAM Users" container:

```
results = service.users().list(query='orgUnitPath=/local/example',customer='my_customer', maxResults=500,orderBy='email').execute()
```

Thanks!

Comment: The error I get is this:
...raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&maxResults=500&alt=json&query=orgUnitPath%3D%2Flocal%2Fexample%2FIAM+Users&orderBy=email returned "Invalid Input: INVALID_OU_ID">

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
results = service.users().list(query="orgUnitPath='/local/example/IAM Users'",
                               customer='my_customer',
                               maxResults=500,
                               orderBy='email').execute()
```